# ROC Curve with Wandb

Tags: roc, resnet, wandb

I have been trying to produce a ROC curve with wandb but it seems that no matter how I reshape y_true and y_score, it doesn't work.

```
            inputs = s['Image'].to(device)
                        
            labels = (s['Class']).type(torch.LongTensor)
            labels = labels.to(device)
            
            outputs = model(inputs)
            
            _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)

            probabilities = F.softmax(outputs, dim=1)[:,1]
                        
            y_pred.extend(preds.data.cpu().numpy())

            y_true.extend(labels.data.cpu().numpy())
            y_score.extend(probabilities.data.cpu().numpy())
            
            wandb.log({"roc" : wandb.plot.roc_curve(y_true, y_score)})
```

Both y_true and y_score are lists with 32 items.
I've also tried to convert them to numpy arrays, but it ends with the same error:

> TypeError: Singleton array array(0.27425554, dtype=float32) cannot be considered a valid collection.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put your data in the shape

```
y_test:  [1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]
y_probas:  [[0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]]
```

hope this helps

Comment: Still the same error unfortunately....

Comment: Sorry you're seeing this. If you can share reproducible code, I'll happily try find a fix for you.